# Ajax form to upload an image an insert values into MySQL at the same time

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

PHP is driving me nuts …

I have a form with some inputs. One of them contains an image. I'm trying to upload the image to the server (which works) and insert the values of the form into a MySQL database at the same time.

```
$("#summaryForm")
.on('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var file_data = $('#message-file').prop('files')[0];
    var form_data = new FormData();
    form_data.append('file', file_data);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'upload.php',
        dataType: 'text', 
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: form_data,
        type: 'post',
        success: function (output) {
            alert(output);
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the trimmed PHP part:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST))
    {
        $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USERNAME,PASSWORD,DB);

        $lat=$_POST['message-lat'];
        $sql="INSERT INTO data (lat) VALUES ('$lat')";
        $result=mysqli_query($sql);
        if($result){

        }
        else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($con);
        }
    }

    if ( $_FILES['file']['error'] > 0 ){
        echo 'Error: ' . $_FILES['file']['error'] . '<br>';
    }
    else {
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'images/' . $_FILES['file']['name']))
        {

        }
    }
```

HTML:

```
<form id="summaryForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action='upload.php' autocomplete="off">
 <input id="message-lat" name="message-lat" type="text"/>
 <input type="file"  data-clear-btn="false" name="image" accept="image/*" capture class="hiddenfile" id="message-file">
 <input type="submit" name="send" value="Submit">
  </form>
```

The image is uploaded properly, but there is no insert into the database.

What should I do?

Comment: What should you do is __explain__ what is not working here.

Comment: Oh sorry, thought that is obvious for an expert, which I'm not. The image is uploaded but there is no insert into the database.

Comment: Have you checked errors while executing sql-query?

Comment: Which input does the image send?

Comment: @Ale I updated the markup

Comment: Your `form_data` has only info about file. What else do you want from it?

Comment: @u_mulder the content of the text-input is not transmitted

Comment: Because you don't add it to form_data?

Comment: @u_mulder how should I? The tutorials I read were for text only and made use of serialization. I'm not sure how to combine this. Any clue?

Comment: Adding other fields is same as adding your file value. Please read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData

Comment: @u_mulder sometimes the easy way is hard to find … thanks a lot!